# Fundamental principle of counting

Tags: combinatorics

I have this question,

> The number of different words that can be formed using all the letters of the word “MATHEMATICS” are?

I solved using the logic that if there are total 11 places so at all the 11 places all the 11 words can come, which gives me 11 to the power 11which is then divided by $2!*2!*2!$ due to the words M, T and A appearing 3 times.

But the actual solution is $11!/(2!*2!*2!)$, why did they consider “not repetition” ?

Comment: Is the usual interpretation of "using all the letters of the word". Example for SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483277/how-many-different-words-can-be-formed-using-all-the-letters-of-the-word-googolp.

Comment: Even if the problem were asking with repetition (which it isn't), your answer would be wrong. Clearly $11^{11}/2^3$ is not an integer. If it were with repetition, the answer would be $8^{11}$ (assuming you mean strings with $11$ letters taken from the alphabet {M,A,T,H,E,I,C,S})..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your power *means* repetition. $11^{11}$ is the cardinal of a cartesian product $X\times\cdots\times X$ (11 times). of a set $X$ with 11 elements.

Comment: Yes, because according to me if the repetition is allowed I can place all 11 letters  in all 11 places then why does the actual answer doesn’t takes repetition into account ?

Comment: @GaganBatra, see my comment.

Comment: @GaganBatra, and if repetition is allowed, the power in any case will be $8^8$ (or $11^8$).

Comment: You mean $8^{11}$ if repetition were allowed (and the word had $11$ letters).

Comment: @anon, right...

Comment: But why can’t I take my answer as 8^11, because there is nothing mentioned about repeatation.

Comment: @GaganBatra, again: because is the usual interpretation.