# How many “words” of any length can be made from the letters in word: MAMMA?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Iam not sure how to solve this question because the word MAMMA has 3 M and 2 A.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Infinity.  Heck, I don't even need the A.

Comment: To clarify: you can make
$$
\begin{split}
& M \\ & MM\\ & MMM\\ & MMMM\\ &\ldots
\end{split}
$$
And this can keep going forever.

Comment: hi.. I meant words by using alfabets from word : MAMMA. the word should not have more than 3 M because the word MAMMA has max 3 M.

Comment: Where are you stuck at? Do you know how many $1$-letter words there are? $2$-letter words? ... Btw there are [5 pages too many of similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=number+of+arrangements+word) already on the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many different words can be formed using all the letters of the word GOOGOLPLEX?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483277/how-many-different-words-can-be-formed-using-all-the-letters-of-the-word-googolp)

Comment: There are a lot of questions about using *all* letters, and most of them have additional conditions. Using only *some* letters is a related but different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important property that we will use is that there are exactly $n\choose k$ words in $\{A,M\}^*$ of length $n$ with $k$ $A$'s, i.e.
$$\#\big\{w\in\{A,M\}^*: |w|=n,|w|_A=k\big\}={n\choose k}.$$
In addition, if $|w|=n$ and $|w|_A=k$, then $|w|_M=n-k$.

The words that can be made from the letters of MAMMA are exactly the words in $\{A,M\}^*$ with at most 2 $A$'s and 3 $M$'s. Therefore, we are looking for the cardinality of the set
$$\big\{w\in\{A,M\}^*:|w|_A\leq2,|w|_M\leq3\big\}$$
We can separate this set into a disjoint union
$$\begin{aligned}
&\coprod_{n=0}^5\big\{w\in\{A,M\}^*:|w|=n,|w|_A\leq2,|w|_M\leq3\big\} \\
= &\coprod_{n=0}^5\coprod_{k=0}^n\big\{w\in\{A,M\}^*:|w|=n,|w|_A=k\leq2,|w|_M=n-k\leq3\big\} \\
= &\coprod_{n=0}^5\coprod_{\substack{k=0\\k\leq 2\\n-k\leq 3}}^n\big\{w\in\{A,M\}^*: |w|=n,|w|_A=k\big\}
\end{aligned}$$
In this last expression, we find a set whose cardinality is known; it's equal to $n\choose k$. Therefore
$$\#\big\{w\in\{A,M\}^*:|w|_A\leq2,|w|_M\leq3\big\}=\sum_{n=0}^5\sum_{\substack{k=0\\k\leq 2\\n-k\leq 3}}^n{n\choose k},$$
and we can calculate that this is equal to
$$(1+1)+(1+2+1)+(3+3+1)+(4+6)+(10)=33.$$

Comment: thank you very much. God bless you