# Find the number of arrangements of BANANA

Tags: combinatorics

**Attempt:**

1. If the Ns appear next to each other

I treat as if there is 1 B, 3 As, 1 N which leads to $\frac{5!}{1!3!1!}$

2. Every N is followed by an A

I count the possible "unique characters" as NA-2, A-1, B-1 so I end up with $\frac{4!}{2!}$

3. the two Ns must be separated

No matter how much I think about it, I'm not sure I can get an answer that doesn't lead me with a headache.

Comment: Why are you trying to solve in this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how many ways can the letters in ARRANGEMENT can be arranged](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236471/how-many-ways-can-the-letters-in-arrangement-can-be-arranged)

Comment: For #3, arrangements with Ns separated = all possible arrangements - arrangements with Ns together.

Answer (score 3):

We have simply -

$\frac {6!}{3! × 2!}$ to arrange alphabets of BANANA.

Dividing by 3! and 2! as we 3 A's and 2 N's.